# Error in loading emulator for windows phone 8 [Can't start the windows phone Emulator]

Tags: windows-phone, emulation, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

Actual error "The Windows Phone Emulator couldn't start because the hypervisor isn't running"

but according to the error i enable the Hyper -V option in term & features in Control panel and restart 2 to 3 times.

and i also do all of thing like checking bios that ENABLE the option virtualization and it is ON in my PC.

I also check core-info via checking Coreinfo.exe .

I do all the step included in below link by microsoft for this kind of issues.

LINK : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Last i check Hyper-V manager and i found no entry of any os,But installing first time visual studio 2012 i found the entry of emulator in that. But now i use the vs2013 Windows Phone SDK 8.0 with no entry in Hyper-V manager.

Error Code : 0x80131500

Answer (score 0):

To run any Windows phone 8 you will need Windows 8 Pro on your computer. I guess thats what you are missing. You can check the full requirements list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
If you are a student try contacting any MSP(Microsoft Student partner) for a genuine Windows 8 Pro key